# Equal Categories

Tags: category-theory, definition, motivation

Let $\infty$ be the "category" of all categories, where the objects are categories and the morphisms are functors. I am trying to motivate the definition of equal categories by doing it as follows.

We say two categories are equal $C=D$, or isomorphic, if there exist functors $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$ such that $G\circ F = \text{id}_C$ and $F\circ G = \text{id}_D$. By $=$ of functors, we mean equality within the category of functors, i.e. $G\circ F = \text{id}_C$ in $\text{Fun}(C,C)$ and $F\circ G = \text{id}_D$ in $\text{Fun}(D,D)$. Thus, there exist natural transformations $\varphi: G\circ F \to \text{id}_C$ and $\psi: F\circ G\to \text{id}_D$ which are isomorphisms.

How does one use this approach to show that it leads to the standard definition of equal categories? (i.e. $F(\varphi_A) = \psi_{F(A)}$ and $G(\psi_B) = \varphi_{G(B)}$).

Comment: Why are you using $\infty$ for the category of categories, instead of $\mathsf{Cat}$? Why are you using "equal" and "isomorphic" as synonyms when (a) category theory is crucially built around not doing that, and (b) you are giving **neither** of them their actual accepted definition? What you have defined is what is known as an ***equivalence*** of categories ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories)).

Comment: Bourbaki botching notation? Hmm . . .

Comment: " (a) category theory is crucially built around not doing that ": I disagree with this statement. One will often tell you that the tensor product of $A^n$ with $A^m$ is $A^{nm}$ (over a commutative ring), even though in the strict equality sense he is wrong. But in a categorical sense, i.e. $A^{nm}$ satisfies the universal property, he is correct.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: The very concept of a braided category ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_monoidal_category)) is built to study the intricacies of all the information you just proposed throwing out.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Unfortunately, what you provide is not relevant to me. The example I gave above, with a tensor product, is one place where we say things are equal, not in a strict set theoretic sense, but in a categorical sense. Another example, a module is the direct limit of its finitely generated sub-modules. In a strict sense, it is not equal, but all authors that I seen write $ M = \lim_i M_i$, and they are fully justified in doing this because they are thinking categorically.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki There is no "categorical sense" to the statement $A^n\otimes A^m = A^{mn}$. It's wrong. The fact that $A^{nm}$ satisfies the universal property for the tensor product means that $A^m\otimes A^n\cong A^{mn}$, which some people may write with an $=$ sign by abuse of notation, but that doesn't in any way diminish the importance of **keeping the actual concepts of "equals" and "isomorphic" separate**. For example, many people use the symbol $2$ to mean both an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ and an element of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, but wouldn't in a million years claim they're "equal".

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: Authors are fully justified in writing the symbol $=$ instead of $\cong$ when it is an abuse of notation providing an increase in clarity that outweighs the cost of actual incorrectness. You have interpreted this occasional expository choice to have mathematical significance which isn't there.

Comment: @ZevChonoles No, I disagree, $A^n \otimes A^m = A^{nm}$, and there is a "categorical sense" to justify this. I think of $A^n \otimes A^m = A^{nm}$ as the statement, "$A^{nm}$ is a tensor product for $A^n$ and $A^m$", you cannot possibly tell me I am wrong with this interpretation. Now, if you think of $\otimes$ as a construction, then yes, they are not equal. But I do not think of $\otimes$ as a construction, I think of it in a more abstract way. In which case I am fully justified in writing that. My tensor symbol is not a construction but notation for some universal property.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: Nothing about what you've written justifies in any way conflating the words "equal", "isomorphic", and "equivalent". If you prefer to write the statement "$A^{nm}$ is a tensor product for $A^n$ and $A^m$" with the sequence of symbols $A^n\otimes A^m=A^{mn}$, that's a perfectly reasonable abuse of the notation $=$ in my opinion. My issue with your post is that **equals doesn't mean isomorphic** and that **neither equals nor isomorphic mean what you wrote**. The fact that a certain abuse of notation is common doesn't mean it is correct to abuse the underlying concepts.

Comment: Since I'm getting the site's message to stop this "extended discussion", and I do not use the chat feature of this site, I will leave my thoughts at that.

Comment: @ZevChonoles "My issue with your post is that equals doesn't mean isomorphic and that neither equals nor isomorphic mean what you wrote.". I never said otherwise, you just misunderstood my use of notation. You may not like my choice of notation but you cannot say it is wrong. Why do I like to write equals? Because, for me, in algebra we care more about the structure then the elements themselves. So I focus on the structure, and categorical language allows me to free myself up.

Comment: @ZevChonoles We can delete all comments? (Maybe modify your first comment a little bit, more suited to me, and leave it at that).

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: just look at the definition of isomorphism in, as you say, "the categorical sense". It has nothing to do with equality. It has to do with a property of arrows in a category $C$. In fact, from what I know of category theory---I am halfway through CWM--special pains are taken to write $\cong $ and not $=$ unless equality is what it meant.

Comment: "You may not like my choice of notation but you cannot say it is wrong." When a notation obscures essential parts of the theory (and the reasoning behind the notation shows a fundamental misunderstanding about the theory), then yes, the notation is wrong. Besides, you may want to clarify what you mean in the last paragraph, because it's not clear (given the preceding abuses of notation) what you really mean.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing three different notions here.

1. Things are *equal* when they are equal. 
    
   Notation: $A=B$.
2. Two objects are *isomorphic* in a category if there exists an invertible arrow between them. 
   Notation: $A\cong B$.
3. Two categories ($A$ and $B$) are *equivalent* if there exists a pair of functors $F,G$ and a pair of natural isomorphisms $G\circ F\to id$ and $F\circ G\to id$. 
   Notation: $A\simeq B$.